# How to replace hard coded JAVA_HOME with environment variable in app startup scripts?

Tags: java, windows, scripting, startup

I am required to replace the hard coded java jre path JAVA_HOME with the environment variable in the all applications' startup scripts in windows 8 server. In scripts, the code like this:
set JAVA_HOME = c:\program files(x86)\java...

These scripts are conf files. I haven't worked on this script before and don't want to screw up the applications. I know in cmd that I can call set JAVA_HOME to get the path from environment variable. Could anybody advise me how to do that in configuration (.conf in my case) scripts? Thanks.

---

Edited: let me be more specific here. The Java service is wrapper and the code is like:
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

Should I just remove the set line and the wrapper.java.command will pick up the right value of JAVA_HOME. Is that correct to say if I don't need set JAVA_HOME to different value from system default, I don't need use set? Thanks.

Comment: The scripts are replacing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you're going to be able to do this.

Environment variables are specific to a command shell interpreter, which is why *nix shells can use different syntax.

If the application is reading the conf file and then applying the path (i.e., the java path to use), then it would have to be prepared to handle that rather than just accept the path as a fully-qualified.

The best bet might be to have a base conf file which has the %JAVA_HOME% (and any other environment variables) baked in and then you generate the run-time conf file with the actual fully-qualified path.  Not sure what Windows tools would be best, might be easier if you have cygwin.

What I'm not understanding is why you are specifying it at all.  Most applications will inherently use JAVA_HOME in the environment, so if you have it set up globally the app should just pick it up, and then nothing in the conf file is required.  I guess if you had multiple java installs and you needed to pick and choose on a per-app basis, but then I'd have the startup script set JAVA_HOME before doing anything else, and again remove it from the .conf and let the app just pick it up.

Comment: I think what I am doing here is avoiding using hard coded path value in scripts because we have multiple Java applications running on the server and we need update JRE when the Oracle releases new update and we have the vulnerabilities. Having the hard coded path removed may save our time and less error-prone? Not sure your last sentence about setting JAVA_HOME at the first place and remove it. Could you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: please take a look at my edited part in my original post. Could I use set.default.JAVA_HOME=... to take the system default JAVA_HOME value automatically when JRE gets updated, and also have a back up option with older installed JRE? Thank you so much.

Comment: perhaps...again, it depends on how java wrapper handles it, but assuming that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your path, then it might work to have wrapper.java.command=java